# Angular localstorage array not showing on HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm saving a list of top 5 high scores in an array in localstorage, but when I try to show it in my HTML it does not appear.

I'm using the GameService.getScores() function to get the array from local storage, and I'm referencing the $scope.scores array to populate my list in HTML.

I'm a noob in Angular an Node.js, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Here is my controller file and my HTML file:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('GameController', function($scope, GameService) 
{
  var highScores = GameService.getScores();
  
  $scope.scores = highScores;

  $scope.submitEntry = function() 
  {
    if (typeof $scope.name === 'undefined' || typeof $scope.word === 'undefined') 
    {
   return;
    }
    
    var entry = {
      name: $scope.name,
   word: $scope.word
    };
    
    var score = GameService.submitEntry(entry);

    var userScore = {
      name: entry.name,
   points: score
  };
   
    if (score > 0)
    {
      if ($scope.scores.length < 5)
      {
        $scope.scores.push(userScore);

        localStorage.setItem("highScores", JSON.stringify($scope.scores));

        return;
      }
      else
      {
        for (let i = 0; i < $scope.scores.length; i++) 
        {
          if (score > $scope.scores[i].points)
          {
            $scope.scores.splice(i, 1, userScore);

            localStorage.setItem("highScores", JSON.stringify($scope.scores));

            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
});

app.service('GameService', function($http) 
{
  this.getScores = function() 
  {
    var hs = [];
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('highScores') != null)
    {
      hs = localStorage.getItem('highScores');

      if (hs) 
      {
        hs = JSON.parse(hs);
      } 
    }
    
    return hs;
 };
  this.submitEntry = function(entry) 
  {
    var score = 0;
    
    var revStr = "";
    var str = entry.word;
    var i = str.length;

    for(var j=i; j>=0; j--)
    {
      revStr = revStr + str.charAt(j);
    }
    if(str == revStr)
    {
      alert(str + " is Palindrome");

      score = str.length;
    }
    else
    {
      alert(str + " is not a Palindrome");
    }

    return score;
 };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
    
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="ng/app.js"></script>

  <body >
    <div ng-controller="GameController" class='container'>
      <h1>Palindrome Game</h1>
    <h2>Submit a new word!</h2>

      <form role='form'>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <input ng-model="name" class='form-control' placeholder="Your name">
          <input ng-model="word" class='form-control' placeholder="Word">
          <button ng-click='submitEntry()' class='btn btn-default'>Submit word</button>
        </div>
      </form>
  
      <h2>Top Scores</h2>
      <ul class='list-group'>
     <li ng-repeat="score in scores | orderBy:'-points'" class='list-group-item'>
      <strong>{{score.name}}</strong> {{score.points}} points
     </li>
    </ul-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: print the `scores` in the template like `{{scores}}`

Comment: Seems to work, you're just bad sorting the data

Comment: Thanks Zooly, what do you mean by sorting the data?

Comment: There is a big difference between angular and angularjs. That are two differenct frameworks. You are using angularjs and you tagged it right but you named it wrong in the title and the question.

Comment: Why do you close a comment (`</ul-->`) but you nowhere open it?

Comment: Just left the closing comment of a previous modification. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: You have to remove the value in `ng-app="app"`. It's only `ng-app`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually working : https://jsfiddle.net/BPagoaga/8jcuqds7/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body >
    <div ng-controller="GameController" class='container'>
      <h1>Palindrome Game</h1>
          <h2>Submit a new word!</h2>

      <form role='form'>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <input ng-model="name" class='form-control' placeholder="Your name">
          <input ng-model="word" class='form-control' placeholder="Word">
          <button ng-click='submitEntry()' class='btn btn-default'>Submit word</button>
        </div>
      </form>

      <h2>Top Scores</h2>
      <ul class='list-group'>
              <li ng-repeat="score in scores | orderBy:'-points'" class='list-group-item'>
                  <strong>{{score.name}}</strong> {{score.points}} points
              </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('GameController', function($scope, GameService) 
{
  var highScores = GameService.getScores();

  $scope.scores = highScores;

  $scope.submitEntry = function() 
  {
    if (typeof $scope.name === 'undefined' || typeof $scope.word === 'undefined') 
    {
            return;
    }

    var entry = {
      name: $scope.name,
            word: $scope.word
    };

    var score = GameService.submitEntry(entry);

    var userScore = {
      name: entry.name,
            points: score
        };

    if (score > 0)
    {
      if ($scope.scores.length < 5)
      {
        $scope.scores.push(userScore);

        localStorage.setItem("highScores", JSON.stringify($scope.scores));

        return;
      }
      else
      {
        for (let i = 0; i < $scope.scores.length; i++) 
        {
          if (score > $scope.scores[i].points)
          {
            $scope.scores.splice(i, 1, userScore);

            localStorage.setItem("highScores", JSON.stringify($scope.scores));

            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
});

app.service('GameService', function($http) 
{
  this.getScores = function() 
  {
    var hs = [];

    if(localStorage.getItem('highScores') != null)
    {
      hs = localStorage.getItem('highScores');

      if (hs) 
      {
        hs = JSON.parse(hs);
      } 
    }

    return hs;
    };
  this.submitEntry = function(entry) 
  {
    var score = 0;

    var revStr = "";
    var str = entry.word;
    var i = str.length;

    for(var j=i; j>=0; j--)
    {
      revStr = revStr + str.charAt(j);
    }
    if(str == revStr)
    {
      alert(str + " is Palindrome");

      score = str.length;
    }
    else
    {
      alert(str + " is not a Palindrome");
    }

    return score;
    };
});
```

I removed this :

```
<script src="ng/app.js"></script>`
```

but I am not sure whether or not it was a problem.

Depending on how you tested your code (code snippet on stackoverflow, jsfiddle) and on which browser, you might encounter some problems with the same-origin-policy.

On chrome I had to uncheck "Block third party cookies" to make it work. On firefox it's still not working, the operation is blocked because the browser considers it to be insecure.

I suggest you try the code locally on your computer rather than in online sandboxes such as jsFiddle.